# Performance issue with ibmjstart/wp-bluemix-objectstorage

Tags: wordpress, ibm-cloud, object-storage

My app is running on WordPress in the bluemix environment. I have an Object Storage service in my bluemix environment where I store all my media files like pictures.

I am using the https://github.com/ibmjstart/wp-bluemix-objectstorage plugin to upload media files directly to the my Object storage when saving media files from the dashboard.

Everything seems to work perfectly - the files get saved to Object storage. However, when I render pages that contain a lot of images, I face a huge lag - my page takes almost 1 minute to render.

I have noticed that the images are saved in the wp_posts table with the url you would expect for WordPress and another row is saved in the wp_postmeta table for mapping the image to the object storage. During render of a page this row is used to change the url of each image and I believe that this is why my webpage is slowing down.

Is there any other solution or have i missed something out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the IBM Object storage V3 service which is still in Beta version. I have decided to change to Object Storage V1 and using the v1.0 of the ibmjstart/wp-bluemix-objectstorage plugin.

My application is now running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Object Storage v3 has moved out of Beta (2/15) 
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/object-storage

Might be worth another look, very curious to see if it was the beta service or if the plugin was causing performance issues.

Comment: Do you think I should try using the standard plan to test it ?

Comment: Might as well try. I don't see v1 listed in the catalog anymore and I cant say with certainty but I assume a migration to v3 would be required at some point in the future.